# Existence of `equiv` for the Compare requirement to be satisfied by a `comp`

Tags: c++

In the C++ named requirement called [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare), a set of properties are listed for two operations called `comp` and `equiv`. In particular, there is one relating the two

```
 equiv(a, b), an expression equivalent to !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)
```

Question: How should I read this requirement? Specially the existence of such operations.

Why the question? Strictly reading the requirement seems to imply that for a method `comp` of a type `T` to satisfy Compare there would need to exist the corresponding method `equiv` such that the condition quoted above is satisfied.

Now, the following code compiles and runs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class A
{
public:
  int x;
  double y;
  A(int x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {};

  bool operator<(A& other)
  {
    return (x < other.x) || (x == other.x && y < other.y);
  };
};

int main()
{
  A a1(1, 3.14);
  A a2(2, 2.71);
  //std::cout << "a1 == a2 = " << (a1 == a2) << std::endl; // Un-commenting this line produces compilation error.
  std::vector<A> v{A(1,1.0), A(2,2.43535), A(5433, 0.5343456), A(-1,34), A(1,4.45435)};
  for (auto elem : v)
  {
    std::cout << "(" << elem.x << "," << elem.y << ") ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
  for (auto elem : v)
  {
    std::cout << "(" << elem.x << "," << elem.y << ") ";
  };
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

printing `v`, ordering the vector in the lexicographic order and printing it ordered.

This means, I assume, that the compiler finds that `A::operator<` satisfies Compare.

However, the compilation error obtained by un-commenting the commented out line suggest me that `A` doesn't have the corresponding `equiv` defined.

Did I read the requirement too strictly? Or maybe there is an `equiv` in this case, but it is not `A::operator==`.

Comment: @RSahu I didn't understand your comment. I also didn't see a mention of the Compare requirement in the [documentation for `std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). What is the connection?

Comment: `equiv` is only shorthand for its equivalent expression. The text would be unreadable without it. And note that equality is a stronger constraint than equivalence.

Comment: @RSahu I added that line to the code above and `g++ --std=c++17 Compare.cpp` complained that `A` didn't have an `operator==`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I see. I should read the line that I quoted as defining, in the context of the requirement, what `equiv` means, instead of as a condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equiv(a, b)` in that requirement isn't a function.  It's just a logical construct used to specify what conditions must hold for a type to meet the Compare requirement.

That is, for an object of type `T` named `comp`, imagine a function named `equiv` that is equivalent to the expression `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.  That hypothetical function would have to meet the outlined requirements, but it isn't actually a thing that exists.  It's just given as a way to specify how `comp` must behave.

---

Note that in your example, `A::operator<` does *not* itself meet the Compare requirements (`A::operator<(a, b)` is not well-formed).  What's actually being used by `std::sort` is `std::less<A>`, which uses the expression `a < b` to do its actual comparison.  For `std::less<A>` to meet the Compare requirements the behavior of the expression `a < b` must specify a strict weak ordering, but it does not meet the Compare requirements itself.